# Checkout GitHub project into Intellij, not showing directories

Tags: github, intellij-idea

When I use "Check out from Version Control" to checkout a project from GitHub into Intellij, even if the project is a simple Web project, Intellij always asks to set up a SDK and also does not show the directories in the Project tab.

What is the right way to checkout a simple (non-Java) project from GitHub into Intellij?

Comment: Any solution on the folder issue? I currently have this issue with IntelliJ 13.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that IntelliJ doesn't detect the project type. Check if it exists a module defined in the project structure config window (menu "File> Project Structure..."). If doesn't exist you have to create it (the "content root" should point to your project root folder).